# Can't deploy Node.js to Azure web sites from Cloud9 IDE

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, ide, cloud9-ide

There appear to be plenty of guides, but none for the new version. Also, Apparently no UI deployment feature for the new version of Cloud9.

I have the Azure WebSite created.
I have the deployment file from Azure for that site
I have the Cloud9 node.js Project ready and working.
I've installed azure package from the Cloud9 Terminal. npm install azure

Duh, so what exactly are the steps/commands for deploying?

Answer (score 1):

In our current release we do not have a UI for deployment yet, but we're going to add those features soon. They have been flaky at times and we really want to offer things that work.

Until then, I'd recommend using the deployment tools straight from the command line in the Terminal - see our documentation site for details: https://docs.c9.io/deploying_via_cli.html.